# Comparing the importance of interactions between models

Tags: predictive-models, interaction, random-forest, interpretation, model

I have two separate models that both use the **same** set of 10 continuous predictor variables.
Model_1 predicts one binary outcome (symptom_1: present vs. not present) and model_2 predicts another binary outcome (symptom_2: present vs. not present).
I am interested in the question if "*interactions in general* " play a stronger role in model_1 compared to model_2. I am not interested in any specific or predefined interaction terms but rather how much a model "makes use" of interactions in general to produce predictions.
I was looking into the H-Stats package (https://github.com/mayer79/hstats) or "model complexity" as described by Molnar & Bischl (https://github.com/slds-lmu/paper_2019_iml_measures). Here is some example code to calculate the proportion of prediction variability unexplained by main effects using H-stats:

```
set.seed(87261)
library(simstudy)
library(hstats)
library(DALEX)
library(ranger)

# simulate data set with 4 predictors, interactions play a strong role
def <- defRepeat(nVars = 4, 
                  prefix = "g", 
                  formula = "1",
                  variance = 1, 
                  dist = "normal")

def <- defData(def, varname="outcome_1", formula="g1*g2*g3*g4", dist = "binary", link="logit")
def <- defData(def, varname="outcome_2", formula="g1+g2+g3+g4", dist = "binary", link="logit")

df <- genData(1000, def)

df_1 <- df %>% dplyr::select(-c(id, outcome_2))
df_2 <- df %>% dplyr::select(-c(id, outcome_1))

# fit ranger to both data sets
fit1 <- ranger(outcome_1 ~ ., data = df_1)
fit2 <- ranger(outcome_2 ~ ., data = df_2)

# generate DALEX explainer for both ranger models
ex1 <- DALEX::explain(fit1, data = dd1 %>% dplyr::select(-c(id, transition)), y = dd1$transition)
ex2 <- DALEX::explain(fit2, data = dd2 %>% dplyr::select(-c(id, transition)), y = dd2$transition)

# calculate hstats for both explainers
s1 <- hstats(ex1)
s2 <- hstats(ex2)

summary(s1)
summary(s2)

h2(s1, normalize = FALSE)
h2(s2, normalize = FALSE)
```

This gives expected results: more unexplained variability for the data simulated with interactions. Is there any way to statistically compare the importance of interactions in general between the two models?

Comment: I'm curious how sex (male vs. female) can be an outcome.

Comment: "interaction strength", is it possible you are looking for an effect size ?

Comment: I never liked the idea of adding predefined interaction terms as predictors in a random forest. However, `ranger()` supports this. You probably want to compare the strength of implicitly defined interactions in a normal random forest with a random forest that takes already interaction terms as input (and adds more implicitly)? Then you *might* extract unnormalized interaction strength via `h2(s, normalize = FALSE)` to get a direct comparison between the two models, check the docu of `?h2` for more. (I am developing {hstats}.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I edited the question and code based on your suggestions to make this more clear

Answer (score 0):

I would use the "dredge" function of the package MuMIN to se what interations receive support in the models within a delta AIC of 2.
Then if you want to know the strength of the effect, I would visualize the significant effects with the "effects" package.